# Advanded API Services > Querying a collection for all entities that do not contain a property?

Tags: apigee

Is there anyway of querying a collection for all entities where a property is either null or does not exist?

Assume the following /cars collection - am I able to query for all cars where there is no colour attribute e.g colour is null ? I would like to get the nissan and mazda cars in my results.

Any ideas?

[
  {
    "name": "ford",
    "colour": "black"
  },
  {
    "name": "toyota",
    "colour": "red"
  },
  {
    "name": "honda",
    "colour": "yellow"
  },
  {
    "name": "nissan"
  },
   {
    "name": "mazda"
  } 
]

Comment: If [this is you](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ikqureshi), then what is the purpose of this question? As an Apigee employee, you should know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this query

```
select * where not ( colour contains '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about using "not".  It will work, but is very non-performant.  It would be better to add "none" as an attribute and then use select * where color='none', or something like that.